# Do we need backend integration for recaptchV3

Tags: invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

We are planning to use recaptcha-V3 on our website. To try this out first and do a phased released - one suggestion was just to have the front-end integration (*without backend integration for site verification*) and then monitor using the reCaptcha console for unusual activities. If we find unusual activities, we'll then turn on an extra verification on the login page (controlled by a switch).

So the key question I have got is  - Can we integrate recaptchaV3 **only on the front-end and not on the backend** - and use the Admin console to monitor activities?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. without any backend integration it can be done but that will not be a good way to implement this . The secret key and as well as the **request token** will be exposed in client browser.

Try this code :

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={recaptchaSiteKey}"></script>
<script>
 grecaptcha.ready(function() {
 grecaptcha.execute('recaptchaSiteKey', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {

var recaptchaSecret={recaptchaSecret};
var responseString = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret="+recaptchaSecret+"&response="+token;

            $.ajax({
            url:responseString
                //your code
            });
          });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Nihar, but what I want to know is can I completely ignore site verification?

Comment: Yes, you can .After getting the response from the API add your code based on the response.  If the rating is <0.5 , enable your extra verification process.

Comment: Thanks - but can you please update the code to have it without the site-verification? I am slightly confused about how that could be done. Also without the site verification, can I see the score on the Admin console of recaptcha?